# adding braces under a matrix in word

Tags: pdf, matrix, ms-word, ms-office

hey everyone i have a small question i am converting some pdfs into word manually and therefore have to write equations by hand. so below attached is the image of a matrix having a curly bracket under it. now the issue is i have typed the matrix but i am unable to figure out how can i place a curly bracket under it. any leads would be appreciated..
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sicno.png).

hey everyone i have a small question i am converting some pdfs into word manually and therefore have to write equations by hand. so below attached is the image of a matrix having a curly bracket under it. now the issue is i have typed the matrix but i am unable to figure out how can i place a curly bracket under it. any leads would be appreciated...

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVP9m.png)

Comment: can you explain in detail? like i am not getting it

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).